# QGIS-R bridge on Linux?

Tags: qgis, r, linux

I'm running R 3.4.4 and QGIS 2.14.9 on a linux server. Is there a possibility to utilize QGIS functions inside R - like the ArcGIS-R-bridge (which sadly only works on Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [RQGIS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQGIS/index.html) for this. The linked CRAN package includes an installation guide for different platforms as well.